# Is it possible to receive e-mail using Google Apps for Work (gmail) with a heroku domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, gmail, google-apps

I have a Google for Work account and I'm creating an e-mail address with my herokuapp domain (e.g. me@myapp.herokuapp.com). I have verified the domain by putting the meta tag in the header of my app. I can send e-mail through gmail from me@myapp.herokuapp.com but for some reason I can't receive e-mail. I'm curious what is causing the problem of the e-mail not going through.

If anyone has some insight, I would appreciate it. I know that it's possible to receive e-mail by using a custom domain in my heroku app, but I don't want to spend the money on a custom domain right now.

Comment: heroku provide you MX record setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by miketreacy, you would need to configure the DNS records for your herokuapp.com subdomain to point to the Google server.
This is not something Heroku allows you to do though. The only way you can send and receive emails from your app is with your own domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Your MX records are not set to Google's. Currently, the MX records are listed as [these](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#MX/myapp.herokuapp.com). In order to receive emails at this domain - in your Apps account - you'll need to modify your DNS to match the [MX records listed on Google's Support site](https://support.google.com/a/answer/174125).